# Add Class into QR Code in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on QR Code into PDF in rails. for that I add into GemFile :-

```
gem 'rqrcode'
```

Than I add into Controller :-

```
@qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new( 'http://github.com/', :size => 4, :level => :h )
```

I want to add class into below code

```
<%= raw @qr.as_svg %>
```

When I was adding the class I am getting error in the screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRXlC.png

When I am not using class this QR Code genrating in below screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ikVU.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ikVU.png

Comment: what is your expected output after adding the class? what will CSS class do?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't.
What you are trying is to pass 2 arguments to `raw` which only takes one string like argument. As documented [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/output_safety_helper.rb#L18)

You could either wrap an element around your qrcode with a class.

```
<div class="test">
  <%= raw @qr.as_svg %>
</div>
```

and then access your svg css via `.test > svg`

or could use the options that are available for [as_svg](https://github.com/whomwah/rqrcode/blob/master/lib/rqrcode/export/svg.rb#L17)

Comment: It is not working. It is not resize the SVG. it just crops the SVG image just like overflow: hidden. suppose SVG size is width: 300px  height: 300px, if i make it width: 100px height: 100px. it will not resize but it will hide the rest 200px part.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to mix two different things. The `image_tag` method takes a source and options, One of which is `:class`. The method `raw` method only takes 1 argument.

Remove it and find another way to add the class to it. Maybe there are some libraries out there that can provide that functionality.